# Hold class names in arraylist and send parameters to their methods in Java

Tags: java

I've asked something similar about that but I didn't get the answer, so I am trying to be straight in here and give as much details as possible. 
Basically I have 5 classes, one of them extends **JFrame** and it's the main class called **TigBase**, second class extends **JPanel**, it's called **Cont** and third, 4th and 5th extends nothing but they have the same methods:

```
public void paintah(Graphics g){
       g.fillRect(20,20,20,20);
```

so **JPanel** should paint it's graphics. But we also don't know the names of those classes. The names of the classes are stored in **Cont** class as a public var

```
public static ArrayList<String> classes = new ArrayList<String>();
```

So I also have a method:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
```

And yeah, the actually names of those classes are **Cutscene0, Cutscene1, Menu2**
And I want the **Cont** class to paint their graphics but can't manage to do that.
If I "knew" the names of the classes I would do it like this:

```
Cutscene0 cut = new Cutscene0();
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
       super.paintComponent(g);
       Cutscene0 cut = new Cutscene0();
       cut.paintah(g);
```

However I might have much more same types of unknown classes so I need to store them in arraylist. I did try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<classes.size;i++){
    Class.forName(classes.get(i)).getMethod("paintah", Graphics.class).invoke(g);
```

But that gives me an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@2c80fb85
```

So yeah, I really need to get it worked out, I was sitting all day researching how I might do that and tried different stuff but they are just not working.. Hope you'll help!

Comment: Split that line up into many steps and see where it fails. Fixing that would be easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the javadoc for `Method.invoke()`:

```
public Object invoke(Object obj,
                     Object... args)
              throws IllegalAccessException,
                     IllegalArgumentException,
                     InvocationTargetException
```

> Invokes the underlying method represented by this Method object, **on the specified object** with the specified parameters.

(emphasis mine).

Your "traditional" method call looks like

```
Cutscene0 cut = new Cutscene0();
cut.paintah(g);
```

To do the same using reflection, you must thus

- create an instance of your class by invoking the no-arg constructor
- invoke the method on this instance

So you would have something like

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(classes.get(i));
Object cut = clazz.newInstance(); // no-arg constructor
Method method = clazz.getMethod("paintah", Graphics.class);
method.invoke(cut, g); // invoke the method on cut, with g as parameter
```

That said, you didn't specify why you don't know the class names. I have the feeling that a proper OO pattern, like a factory, could make things clearer. At the very least, all your classes could implement the same interface `Painter`, and you could then just do

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(classes.get(i));
Painter cut = (Painter) clazz.newInstance(); // no-arg constructor
cut.paintah(g);
```

Comment: I assumed he still wanted to be able to dynamically load classes by their name. There are valid use-cases for doing that. But I agree that if he can have a collection of Painter, then he should do that and avoid reflection.

Comment: Yes I just realized that he is not clear about being able to create or not instances of each class, so I have deleted my comment as irrelevant (perhaps I shouldn't have) +1

Comment: You JB Nizet, won! Holy damn it worked, thank you very much! However I didn't hear anything about interfaces, so you gave me a new subject to research about.

Comment: You're using reflection, which is quite an advanced topic, without having heard about interfaces, which are a basic and essential part of OO? Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your exception: from [Method javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html):

> A Method permits widening conversions to occur when matching the
>   actual parameters to invoke with the underlying method's formal
>   parameters, but it throws an `IllegalArgumentException` if a `narrowing
>   conversion` would occur.

But anyway I think you should avoid reflection if you can and use interface instead of string classname:

```
interface Paintable {
  public void paintah(Graphics g)
}

public static ArrayList<Paintable> ps = new ArrayList<Paintable>();

for(int i = 0; i<ps.size;i++){
    ps.get(i).paintah(g)
}
```

Comment: The reason of the exception is not the one you think. Read my answer.